# Showing value(s) by slug instead of showing by name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've done a lot of Googling and tested a few codes, but I couldn't find any solution. When I create a new product in WooCommerce, I need to add attributes and then add their value(s). By default, the value(s) dropdown shows values by name. How can I change it to show values by slug?

I have a lot of values with the same name but different images and slugs, so it's better to choose the value by its slug rather than its name.

I found something similar for my problem. But it's not working.

functions.php file:

```
// Show attribute label + slugs in wordpress admin product editing pages.
function show_attribute_slugs_in_product_edit_page( $hook ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'product' === $post->post_type ) {     
            wp_enqueue_script(  'show_slugs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/show_slugs.js' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'show_attribute_slugs_in_product_edit_page', 10, 1 );
```

js/show_slugs.js

```
(function( $ ){
    var attr_renamed = false;
    $(document).on('click', '#woocommerce-product-data > div.inside > div > ul > li.attribute_tab > a', function(){ 
        if (attr_renamed === false) {
            $("#product_attributes > div.toolbar.toolbar-top > select option").not(":nth-child(1)").each(function() {
                var attr_label = $(this).text();
                var attr_value = $(this).val().replace('pa_', '');
                $(this).text(attr_label + ' (' + attr_value + ')');
                attr_renamed = true;
            });
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

This code was written by Morteza Rahmani.

Comment: Why would you want this? Aren’t the names clear enough?

Comment: Because I have a lot of values with the same name but with different images and slugs, so it's better chose the value with slug rather than name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no hook for that. You should resort to Javascript to accomplish this. In jQuery, this code takes the option's values and replace the innerHTML with those values.

```
jQuery(function($){
    let options = $(".attribute_taxonomy option");
    for(let i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        let option = options[i];
        let slug = $(option).attr("value");
        $(option).html(slug);
    }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't make any progress with this code, thanks.

Comment: Then you did something wrong with the code. Did you place it in a separate file and loaded it using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook? Or what did you do with it? It works and it is about the only solution to your problem.

Comment: I created a custom-script.js in the same folder as functions.php in child theme for your code. And added this code in functions.php:
function enqueue_custom_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-script.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script' );

Comment: Since you are using a child theme, you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`.

Comment: The template directory is the parent theme’s directory…

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the file loaded? Do you see it in the developer tools?